# Cost constant of pseudocode

Tags: algorithm, constants, pseudocode

I understand where the cost comes from for lines 1-4, 6, and 9-10. But why is the cost of line 5 10 and the cost of line 7 6?

```
Max-Heap-Increase-Key(A[1...n]: array of number, i: 1<= i <= n, key)
1 if key < A[i]
2     then print  " " 
3 A[i] = key
4 parent = floor(i/2) 
5 while i > 1 and A[parent] < A[i] 
6    temp = A[i]
7    A[i] = A[parent] 
8    A[parent] = temp
9    i = parent
10   parent = floor(i/2)
```

The constant cost for a single execution of each line are as follows: 
1) 5, 
2) 1,
3) 4,
4) 4,
5) 10,
6) 4,
7) 6, 
8) 4, 
9) 2,
10) 4

Count cost 1 for: reading a variable, writing to variable, using an array index to locate memory location, reading or writing to array index, arithmetic op, comparison (where <= or >= counts twice) and a boolean operation.

Comment: Where did this analysis come from?

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at line 5:

```
while i > 1 and A[parent] < A[i]
```

According to the rules for what we should count:

- *Reading a variable:* `i` is read twice, `A` twice, and `parent` once, so there are five read operations.
- *Reading from an array:* Twice from the array `A`.
- *Comparison:* One `>` and one `<`, so there are two comparisons.
- *Boolean operation:* One `and`.

Total cost is 10.

---

And line 7:

```
A[i] = A[parent]
```

According to the rules:

- *Reading a variable:* `A` is read twice, `i` once, and `parent` once.
- *Reading from an array:* Once, on the right-hand side.
- *Writing to an array:* Once, on the left-hand side.

So the total cost is 6.

---

It remains uncertain what *"using an array index to locate memory location"* is supposed to mean if this is different to *"reading or writing to array index"*. Perhaps this should be counted instead of loading the variable `A`? That would be strange, but it is also strange to describe it as a separate cost from reading/writing to an array.

Generally speaking, a variable like `A` holds a pointer to an array, so accessing an array like `A[i]` requires loading that pointer, then loading the index variable, and then doing the read or the write. The read or write operation consumes the pointer and index loaded in the previous two operations.